# how do I specify a unique name for a Java libs folder?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf, libs

How do I package a Jar so that the libs folder has a unique name?

The root problem is that, for multiple Java programs on the Desktop, do they share a common libs folder?  What if there are version clashes?

[One jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) doesn't interest me as a solution, I would like to just name the folders "app1Libs", or something along those lines.

Comment: Why don't you create user library for your jars ?

Comment: something like this:  http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/jar-libraries.html#appendix_userlibs  might work.

Comment: I think he doesn't need to share `lib` between workspaces :(